# Using Python to create a simulation

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I have these five lists:

```
list_1 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
list_2 = ['2','4','6','8','10']
list_3 = ['3','6','9','12','18']
list_4 = ['1','3','5','7','9']
list_5 = ['2','3','5','7','8']
```

What I am trying to do is make a simulation that will have drop down menus, where each menu 1 through 5 is correlated with each list 1 through 5 respectively.
But, the trick is that if there is a string value that is already choosen and present in one of the menus, the other menus that has the same string value will no longer have that as an option.

For example, '3' is present in list_1, list_3, list_4, and list_5.If I choose '3' for menu 4, then the option of '3' will no longer be available for list_1, list_3, and list_5.

What I have done:
I imported the itertools library, so I could find all possible combinations of the lists, respective to each menu.

```
import itertools
combos = list(itertools.product(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5))
```

I know this might not be useful for the actual code later, but I thought it would be a good reference point. Next, I started looking into libraries that might be useful for this approach, I found tkinter was a good library.

```
import tkinter as tk

# Creating the main window
window = tk.Tk()
```

After this point, I'm sort of confused. How should I go about trying to code? I'm using the following documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

I've tried playing around with it, and was able to make a click me button, though this is not what I want:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Creating the main window
window = tk.Tk()

# Click me button to the main window
button = tk.Button(window, text="Click Me")
button.pack()

# Running Tkinter loop for button
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could try to separate your logic, deal first with the problem of making sure your menus would behave as you want them (just print out for start), then find the tool to create the menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a Tkinter window that enables and disables menu items as per your description. If menu_item `3` is selected, then that menu is disabled, and the rest are enabled.

Here is the code:

#### Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import copy


def disable_menuitem(menu_item):
        enable_all_menus()
        for i, m in enumerate(menu_list_items):
            if menu_item in m:
                menus[i].entryconfig(m.index(menu_item)+1, state="disabled")
                print(f"List{i} - menu value {menu_item}")


# Function to enable all of the menu items  
def enable_all_menus():
    for i, m in enumerate(menu_list_items):
        for j in m:
            menus[i].entryconfig(m.index(j), state="normal")

# Create the Frame and menubar
root = Tk(className=' Example by ScottC')
root.geometry("200x200")
ttk.Entry(root).grid()
menubar = Menu(root)

# Create the menu widgets
menu1 = Menu(menubar)
menu2 = Menu(menubar)
menu3 = Menu(menubar)
menu4 = Menu(menubar)
menu5 = Menu(menubar)

menus = [menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4, menu5]
    
# Add menu widgets to the menubar
for i, m in enumerate(menus):
    menubar.add_cascade(menu=m, label=f"List{i+1}")


# Define the names of each menu
list_1 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
list_2 = ['2','4','6','8','10']
list_3 = ['3','6','9','12','18']
list_4 = ['1','3','5','7','9']
list_5 = ['2','3','5','7','8']
menu_list_items = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5]

# Add menu items to the menu widgets
for i, l in enumerate(menu_list_items):
    for item in l:
        menus[i].add_command(label=item, command=lambda y=item: disable_menuitem(y))
        
root['menu'] = menubar
root.mainloop()
```

##### Output when 3 is selected:

[image: List1]

[image: List3]

[image: List4]

[image: List5]